# Strange Facebook 'Like' button behavior

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just gone through implementing the FB Like button on a site, and on some product pages it works as expected (like count increments, posts on wall), on some the count increments and is immediately reset to nothing but still shows up on wall.

Grabbed the based code for the button from FB just yesterday and here's what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >
```

... meta tags: ( not allowed to disclose/post any client identifying info though:-(  )

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="000000"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Some Client In QA" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Some Client In QA product title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://client.in.qa/product/pix/somepix.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://client.in.qa/product/product1234" />
<meta property="og:description" content="product description" />
```

... right after the opening  tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

... the button itself:

```
<fb:like href="http://client.in.qa/product/product1234" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

The strange stuff:
When I started out on it I was using the admins ID provided by the client and when running the url through fb linter, the only error it gave is
 `Object at URL 'http://client.in.qa/product/product1234' of type 'product' is invalid because the given value '000000' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.` but when I looked at the response in Firebug after clicking 'like', the error mentioned invalid app_id.

At that point I'd click the button, the count would increment and immediately revert, but it would show up on my wall.

So I set up a test app on FB and entered the `client.in.qa` as App Domain and `http://client.in.qa` as Website and used my own app id on fb:admins meta-tag.

Then the 'like' count would increment and hold. I thought all's well. But..., turns out it does not work on all products. And the same error shows up on linter, even for the product pages where the buttons seems to work as expected.

Clicking the URLs Graph API reveals:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
It seems that until FB crawls the site the only way to get consistent behavior is run the url to be liked through the linter. Then the little preview shows up when I try to 'Like' it and the count 'sticks'